# laravel validation during ajax request

Tags: ajax, validation, laravel, request, response

Please somebody explain this info from Laravel docs "When using the validate method during an AJAX request, Laravel will not generate a redirect response. Instead, Laravel generates a JSON response containing all of the validation errors. This JSON response will be sent with a 422 HTTP status code."

What does "during an AJAX request" exactly mean here?

If I'm set like this:

1. User submits input from a form in the view.
2. The route calls the method for post in the controller
3. The request is validated in the controller

case 1) Request passes validation and input is stored in the DB -> Response is returned as JSON for a script that updates the view on the fly.

case 2) Request doesn't pass validation, what is returned here? I think a redirect and if not how can you check if validation has failed to return a JSON instead?

And is this scenario similar to what the docs talk about? If not then what?

Answer (score 0):

The response to an AJAX call in this case is a JSON string
Case 1: as you said
Case 2: A JSON String with the error messages. Look into your Chrome dev tools into the Network tab, there you'll see the exact responses.

Comment: I know about that, what I'd like to understand is how is validator involved in sending the JSON response. I mean, if I craft my JSON after validation what I am sending is, as set, my crafted JSON and not an instance of validator. So should I send $validator instead?

Comment: If a Laravel validation rule is triggered cause of missing or false data, the validator triggers a response it self. None of your code will be executed.

Comment: Ok but what if you use validate instead of validator ? How do you trigger the response?

Comment: `$this->validate($request, [
            'post_id' => 'required',
            'body' => 'required'

        ]);` I mean this instead of `$rules = array(

            'post_id' => 'required',
            'body' => 'required'
        );

        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);


        if ($validator->fails())
        {
            return Response()->json($validator);
        }
        else
        { something }`

Answer (score 0):

When handling a validation failure, laravel automatically generates an error response. Normally this will redirect the user back to their form, but in the case of an AJAX request it will instead return a JSON response with the details of what failed validation.

Laravel relies on the symfony request object to detect AJAX requests, specifically [this line](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/master/Request.php#L1676): 
`return 'XMLHttpRequest' == $this->headers->get('X-Requested-With');`

If you are encountering issues with your requests not being treated as AJAX, make sure your client is properly setting the `X-Requested-With` header